# How do I clean up after multiple installations

Tags: system-installation

I have a computer with two hard drives. The smaller one is a SSD. I accidentally installed Ubuntu on both drives. How do I safely remove the installation on the non-SSD drive?

This might help:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL

NAME                         FSTYPE        SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                      238.5G            
├─sda1                       vfat          512M /boot/efi  
├─sda2                       ext2          244M /boot      
└─sda3                       LVM2_member 237.8G            
  ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-0)   ext4        221.9G /          
  └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-1) swap         15.9G [SWAP]     
sdb                                        1.8T            
├─sdb1                       swap         22.4G [SWAP]     
└─sdb2                       ext4          1.8T            
sr0                                       1024M
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I safely remove the installation on the non-SSD drive?

- Boot into the OS you want to keep.
- Install and start gParted (`sudo apt-get install gparted` if not already available).
- Remove the partitions that point to the 2nd install. gParted will show you labels that identify the operating system. As a bonus: you can not delete mounted partitions so using the OS you want to keep locks those partitions.

From the list you posted I would say: remove `sdb` or (if you want to use it in this OS) format as ext4 and create a mountpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are booted into the SSD version, I'd simply say: repartition your `/dev/sdb` with the tools of your liking. (`fdisk`, `gdisk`, `gparted`, `gnome-disks`...)

However, I'm going to warn about two things.

a) You can see that your swap is used on that disk.  I'd make sure that the swap is not used in your `/etc/fstab` any more.  Do the following:

```
$ sudo blkid /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1: UUID="12345678-1234-1234-1234-123412341234" TYPE="swap"
```

Note the string between quotes for the `UUID`.  Edit your `/etc/fstab` file and remove the line that looks like this:

```
UUID=2345678-1234-1234-1234-123412341234" none swap sw 0 0
```

This will tell your system to forget about that second 22GB swapfile.  Reboot now, or, easier `sudo swapoff /dev/sdb1`.

At this point, the whole disk `/dev/sdb` is ununsed.  Start partitioning it.

b) Unless you are absolutely 100% sure that you are booting from /dev/sda, reinstall `grub` before rebooting:

```
$ sudo grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
```

Obviously, the output is what my machine tells me.  Yours will vary.